# Transfer personnel between tiers

Tags: world-of-tanks

If you assign a medium tank commander to a heavy tank, his rating drops significantly.  Does he also 'forget' how to command a heavy tank?  Or conversely, what happens when he is reassigned back to a heavy?  Does the same rule hold true for perks?  I.e., does he have to learn repair all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The medium tank crewman assigned to a heavy tank has a penalty since he's not in a medium tank. He still knows how to operate a medium tank since he is still a medium tank crewman. The penalty does not apply to any skills or perks that have been earned, such as repair.

You can also retrain a medium tank crewman for another class, such as a heavy tank. The new 'heavy tank crewman' may lose some operating efficiency depending on how much you pay for retraining, and he does 'forget' how to drive a medium tank without penalty. Skills and perks levels remain the same.